# Is there any restricion when using LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY in foreground service?

Tags: android, android-location, google-location-services

When app running in foreground and activity is visible to the user then using `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`  in a bound service I am able to receive location updates in the bound service but when the app is in the background and the same bound service running as foreground service using `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` does not give location updates but if I use LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY then I am able to receive the location updates in the foreground service.

Does android put any kind of restriction when using `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` in foreground service?